# Connecting to database - Object doesn't contain constructor that takes 1 argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I am trying to create a connection to the database and i am running into this error and not sure where to start or what to fix.

**Error:**
'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument

```
 public partial class DocMgmtDataContext
{
    public DocMgmtDataContext()
        : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectS"].ConnectionString)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
}
```

**In App.config**

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProjectS" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OverallProg;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What does `DocMgmtDataContext` inherit from? The error clearly says that `object` doesn't contain constructor with 1 parameter.

Comment: @shahkalpesh i myself am confused not sure i am trying to follow and example in setting up a connection string so i can access the database.

Comment: Can you cite the source of the example? Is this related to Entity framework?

Comment: @shahkalpesh yes related to entity framework. I created a library and i am trying to connect to the database to further use the library. the example i am using is another project someone wrote but seems like i am missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit your class from [`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). The constructor constructs a new context instance using the given string as the name or connection string for the database to which a connection will be made.

```
public partial class DocMgmtDataContext :DbContext
{
    public DocMgmtDataContext()
        : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectS"].ConnectionString)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
}
```

Comment: So will i have to generate the class DbContext passing the string in it?

Comment: @loop852 It is built in class under system.data.entity

Comment: I imported using system.data.entity and referenced it but it is still underlined saying that i am missing directive or assembly reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EF then check out the following steps that you have followed or not.

1. Create library project => right click on project file => add new item => choose data section from left pane => select ADO.net Entity data model.
2. it will popup with one window where you need to select generate from database option.(database first) and click next.
3. in next window you have to select your database to which you want to connect with.
4. EF automatically generates EDMX file which contains two parts one is context class and 
   another is all classes(entities) for you.
5. in context class you can find the constructor that you are talking about having connection string as parameter.
6. now you need to just use this class library in your project and to access database you need to make context class object. and with this object you can do your all CRUD operations easily.
7. These are just simple steps to connect to database. I may not have added every steps but I think these are also useful steps. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The `DataSource` is of the form `<ServerName>\<InstanceName>`. The `.` refers to the local server. But you are missing the instance name

Answer (score 0):

Your class `DocMgmtDataContext` is inheriting from `object`, this is why you're getting the error *'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument*.